# How to turn off the Siri dictation "beep" sound on macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, catalina, voice-dictation

Before Catalina there was an option to turn off the "beep" sound. ( The sound you have when you double press Fn button ) Now that option is gone in Catalina. And the trick to remove the sound file does not work with Catalina SiP.

Are there any sane way to get rid of that beeping sound before Siri dictation?

Note: This is not Voice Control Dictation, Which was previously known as Enhanced Dictation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the sound the system makes when a spoken speech command is recognized, and you are running MacOS Catalina, you can enable or disable that option in System Preferences/ Accessibility/ Voice Control.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I should have been clear. Voice Control is a replacement for previously known as "Enhanced Dictation" which is speed recognition on devices. I was referring to Siri Voice dictation.